# Pointer to Vectors in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm struggling with vectors. Here is my two examples.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main ()
{
    std::vector<int> myvector (5); 
    int* p = myvector.data(); // 0 index address
    *p = 10; // index 0 = 10;
    ++p; // index 0 to 1
    *p = 20; // index 1= 20
    p[2] = 100; // index 2 = 100
    ++p; // as p was in index 1. then ++ goes to index 2.
    *p=49; // index 2 = 49,, and 100 goes on index up
    std::cout << "myvector contains:";

    for (int i=0; i<myvector.size(); i++)
    std::cout << ' ' << myvector[i];

    std::cout << '\n';
return 0;
}
```

Output: ( As I explain in my each statement )

```
10 20 49 100 0
```

But when I comment/remove `++p` & `*p=49;` then why 100 is still on 3 index in vectors? Here is the example that is confusing me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main ()
{
    std::vector<int> myvector (5); 
    int* p = myvector.data(); 
    *p = 10; // index 0=10;
    ++p; // index 0 to 1
    *p = 20; // index 1 = 20
    p[2] = 100; // index 2 = 100
    std::cout << "myvector contains:";

    for (int i=0; i<myvector.size(); i++)
    std::cout << ' ' << myvector[i];

    std::cout << '\n';
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
10 20 0 100 0
```

Can any one explain 2nd output?

Comment: Have you realized that `std::vector` is not a raw array?

Comment: You do `++p` & `*p=49;` **after** you set 100 so how later code can affect earlier code?

Comment: @Andrey I just was confused about `vector.insert(); that not replace the value, but move the array to up.

Comment: @UnKnown you don't have any 'vector.insert()' in your code

Comment: @Andrey I know, but was confused. Sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your comment in `p[2] = 100; // index 2 = 100` is wrong as `p` already is at index `1`, so `p[2]` is index 3.

`p[2]` is equivalent to `*(p + 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why you would believe that the result of

```
p[2] = 100;
```

would depend on what happens afterwards, but anyway...

I'll introduce an extra variable that can be used as a reference point for the start of the vector.
See comments for explanation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main ()
{
    std::vector<int> myvector (5);
    int* start = myvector.data() // Reference point 
    int* p = myvector.data();
    *p = 10;    // Equivalent to p[0] = 10 and start[0] = 10
    ++p;        // p is now start + 1
    *p = 20;    // Equivalent to p[0] = 20 and start[1] = 20
    p[2] = 100; // Since p == start + 1, this is equivalent to start[3] = 100
    ++p;        // p is now start + 2
    *p=49;      // Equivalent to p[0] = 49 and start[2] = 49
    std::cout << "myvector contains:";

    for (int i=0; i<myvector.size(); i++)
    std::cout << ' ' << myvector[i];

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight after `int* p = myvector.data();`, `*p` refers to `myvector[0]` and for any `n`, `p[n]` refers to `myvector[n]`.  You could think of the memory locations as columns, with each having equivalent names as below:

```
myvector[0]  myvector[1]  myvector[2]  myvector[3]  myvector[4]
p[0]         p[1]         p[2]         p[3]         p[4]
*p
```

When you do `++p` though, you shift where `p` points, and therefore where `p[0]` is, and all the other indexed access:

```
myvector[0]  myvector[1]  myvector[2]  myvector[3]  myvector[4]
p[-1]        p[0]         p[1]         p[2]         p[3]
             *p
```

That's why the `p[2] = 100` in your second program affects `myvector[3]`.

FWIW, if you do a second `++p` you have:

```
myvector[0]  myvector[1]  myvector[2]  myvector[3]  myvector[4]
p[-2]        p[-1]        p[0]         p[1]         p[2]
                          *p
```

(That's the situation in your first program when you use `*p=49;` to set `myvector[2]`)